# Where is Qt::escape(const QString & plain) in Qt4.8.6?

Tags: html, c++, qt, qstring

I need the Qt::escape(const QString & plain), but it seems to be deprecated in my version of Qt 4.

This is my version of Qt4, I am using update-to-date Debian sid distro.

> me@debian$ dpkg -l | grep qt4-default
>   ii qt4-default 4:4.8.6+git64-g5dc8b2b+dfsg-2+b1 amd64 Qt 4 development defaults package

I googled and searched in Qt's online document, it only tells me it is deprecated in Qt 5. And in Qt5, I can use

> QString result = aQString.toHtmlEscaped();

but where is Qt::escape in Qt 4.8.6

And is there other convenient way to do the same thing in several lines of code?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you search sources of Qt [4.8.6](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/source/8ab1ad64620ff9d0453a326010d161ea68a63a2f:) you will find it declared [here](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/source/8ab1ad64620ff9d0453a326010d161ea68a63a2f:src/gui/text/qtextdocument.h#L87) and defined [here](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/source/8ab1ad64620ff9d0453a326010d161ea68a63a2f:src/gui/text/qtextdocument.cpp#L159).

Answer (score 0):

google for  Qt::escape(const QString & plain):
https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/dfaures-qtbase/commit/02bbcbfef7aa102da1e4cad48967571ff9737964

Answer (score 0):

It's defined in qtextdocument.h as

```
namespace Qt
{
  QString escape(const QString& plain);
}
```